# Store user selection with jQuery localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a sticky banner on my site that encourages users' to signup to a newsletter. But it can be annoying, If it constantly appears on a page, Could frustrate the user.

So, I've added a cross to the banner, to close it. What I'd like to do is once its been selected as closed, Store it in some form of localstorage, Check against that and show / hide the banner dependent on whether the user has closed it or not.

Is this possible, If so how would I go about doing it.

Thanks

Comment: Yes you could do this. But i would recommend you simply just use cookies for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible and you are thinking on right way.

Here is the **[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/mL3pe5a4/)**

**Assumption HTML and JS**

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="sticky">
Do not show on close
</div>
<button class="close">
Close sticky
</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var localStor=localStorage.getItem("stickyClosed"); //get the localstorage value
    if(localStor=="true") //check if its true
        $('.sticky').hide(); //hide or remove the sticky element
})

$('.close').on('click',function(){
    $('.sticky').remove(); //remove on click of close
    localStorage.setItem('stickyClosed','true') //set localstorage value
})
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)